# Mongo projection result as an array of selected items

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

For the given documents in the mongo

```
{"_id" : "joe":  
  grocerylist: [ "cheddar", "apple", "oranges" ]
} 
{"_id" : "joanna":  
grocerylist: [ "cheddar", "foobar" ]
}
{"_id" : "john": 
grocerylist: [ "apple", "oranges" ]
}
```

If I search for user with cheddar in their list

```
find({"grocerylist" : cheddar}, fields={'_id' : 1})
```

I get

```
[{u'_id': u'joe'}, {u'_id': u'joanna'}]
```

Using Mongo, how can I get just a list of matched users, like this..

```
[u'joe', u'joanna']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_id`s are unique across the collection, thus you can use [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) here.

```
collection.distinct('_id', {'grocerylist' : cheddar})
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a list comprehension:

```
cursor = db.col.find({"grocerylist" : cheddar}, fields={'_id' : 1}) 
print([document['user'] for document in cursor])
```

Comment: @alexce: Thanks. That is what I ended up doing. Is there a mongo (projection or some other) command to do it? Rather that doing it outside in Python